# Normalisation methodology and batch effect

Tags: r, machine-learning, normalization, methodology

I have a question about the normalization of datas and batch effect ...
For example, here is a dataset :

```r
(list(PatientID = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P4", "P5", 
   "P5", "P6"), LesionResponse = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
   2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
   pyrad_tum_original_shape_LeastAxisLength = c(19.784, 
   15.070, 21.065, 11.804, 27.398, 17.058, 4.904, 4.784, 6.217, 
   5.963, 5.301), pyrad_tum_original_shape_Sphericity = 
   c(0.652,0.773, 0.723, 0.715, 
   0.707, 0.811, 0.836, 0.863, 0.851, 0.746), 
   pyrad_tum_log.sigma.5.0.mm.3D_firstorder_Skewness = c(0.367, 
   0.117, 0.099, -0.174,-0.863, -0.848, -0.425,-0.492, 0.0105, 
   0.249), pyrad_tum_log.sigma.5.0.mm.3D_glcm_Contrast = 
   c(0.376,0.548, 0.267, 2.900, 0.322, 0.221, 1.900, 0.971, 
   0.315,0.653),   
   pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_GrayLevelNonUniformityNormalized = 
   c(0.154,0.176, 0.171, 0.218,0.345, 0.164, 0.104,0.128, 0.137, 
   0.133), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_LargeAreaEmphasis = 
   c(27390.281,11327.793, 51566.794, 7261.687, 340383.536,22724.779, 
   45.974, 142.588, 266.744,1073.452), 
   pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_LargeAreaLowGrayLevelEmphasis = 
   c(677.011, 275.281, 582.131, 173.747, 6140.739, 558.277, 1.810, 
   4.557, 6.517,19.144), 
   pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_SizeZoneNonUniformityNormalized = 
   c(0.411,0.339, 0.425, 0.355, 0.294, 0.339, 0.351, 0.394, 0.360, 
   0.369)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
   "data.frame"))
```

Here are the questions : I have to normalize the data of this table, I deduce that it would be better to realize a normalization by columns... However, there are rows belonging to the same individuals. This would introduce a bias in the constitution of my model, wouldn't it ? (does the fact that some of my rows are from the same sample will affect the normalization ?) How can I remedy this?
Second question: My patients' data were not collected with the same scanner ... is this a batch effect? If so, should I correct it before normalization? or after?